# Can'nt Access JSON From The GIven URL Do'nt Know Why?

Tags: android, json

`        package com.tricks.readjsonfromurl;

```
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.StrictMode;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.widget.ScrollView;
    import android.widget.TextView;



    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .detectDiskReads()
                    .detectDiskWrites()
                    .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
                    .penaltyLog()
                    .build());

            TextView showJSON = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.JSONfromURL);

            //ScrollView ScrollJSON = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

            JSONObject json = null;

            String str = "";
            HttpResponse response;
            HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //This the url from which i am expecting to get JSON Data.

            HttpGet myConnection = new HttpGet("http://www.clusterdev.com/flipkart-api-demo/category-example.html");

//Same Code but different URL i've commented below and this URL is //returning Data WTF??
            //HttpGet myConnection = new HttpGet("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/station?bbox=12,32,15,37,10&cluster=yes");



            try
            {
                response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
                str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

            }
            catch (ClientProtocolException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try
            {
//Getting nothing from the URL.

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);    

                String showJSONIntoTextView = jsonObject.toString();

                showJSON.setText(showJSONIntoTextView);


            }

            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }`I want to get `JSON` Data from the `URL`, `URL` contains `JSON` data only but giving nothing.
```

http://www.clusterdev.com/flipkart-api-demo/category-example.html

All i want to do is to return `JSON` data from the above URL 
and show it in an Android TextView.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Can you please let us know what exactly you have tried in your code?

Comment: ok i m going to paste the code.

Comment: your page is an html page. it looks like a json file, but it is not.

Comment: so there is probably a very clear exception is the logcat, but apparently you can't be bothered...

Answer (score 1):

```
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        URL url=new URL(serviceURL);
        HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        String urlParameters = data;

        switch (REQTYPE) {
            case 0:
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                break;
            case 1:
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");

                if(urlParameters.trim().length()>0) {
                    // Send post request
                    con.setDoOutput(true);
                    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
                    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
                    wr.flush();
                    wr.close();
                }


                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + serviceURL);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder resp = new StringBuilder();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            resp.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println(resp.toString());
        Response = resp.toString();


    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return Response;
}
```

Create a class which extend AsyncTask do the following stuff...in Background

Comment: where i need to add all this in my code cause in the way i merge it doesnt work